# Which type of ethernet cable to connect ethernet socket to a switch

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have an ethernet socket than I need to connect it to a switch. The contractor seems to forget to crimp the head that is suppose to be connected to a switch for me. Which type of arrangement do I need to crimp it with. Straight or cross over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually switches need a cross-over cable only to connect with other switches (or the same-class devices like hubs), so I'd say you need a straight-through cable.

Comment: Mostly true, but ... I don't even remember the last time I had a device that _needed_ a cross-over cable. Pretty much all switches support Auto-MDIX these days, and so do most network cards. (For Gigabit Ethernet it's outright required.)